ERROR Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNSModule': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
ERROR  Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNSModule': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mobileshopsten-IcVyHbRbrXxvgT_ZScpMUg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mobileshopsten-IcVyHbRbrXxvgT_ZScpMUg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mobileshopsten-IcVyHbRbrXxvgT_ZScpMUg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "librnscreens.so", js engine: hermes
LOG  Running "MobileShopsTen" with {"rootTag":241}
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "MobileShopsTen" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I did nothing just installed react native screens then this error ruined my 5days Please help me
I did nothing just installed react-native screens thats it error ruined my 5 days

This exact similar Issue was Just faced by me
The following solution Worked For me...
I am Using "react-native": "0.68.2",
My Android Its Gradle version is 8.0
i Searched For Gradle 8.0 release date
Then Accordingly I Just searched For React-Native-screen Package, for Same Date Version here
Then I Just Update That package
npm i react-native-screens@3.29.0
Might Be Different In your case according To Your Gradle version
Then Run
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native run-android
hope this Would work for You As well

I have the same issue.
On React Native: 0.70.5
The project was running fine on another Mac.
However, after moving the project to a new Mac M1, the same issue appeared.
If it's AwesomeProject 0.70.5, it can run is fine.
Update:
I have removed some old packages. Now it is working fine.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
